# Get a string with characters and ints and use them separately C++

Tags: c++, string, get, getline

I need to take in input as a string like this:

```
add 4
cancel 200
quit
```

and use them as commands.

For example:
getting `add [n]` would tell the program to use the `add` function and to use the value of `int 4`.

How do I take in a string like this all at once and use the command word and the int sparely?

Comment: I would use `std::getline` to get the line and then use `std::istringstream` to carve up the line.

Comment: I think you won't get a help without showing your trial. you can use `stoi` after getting the whole line in a `string` to get the `int` after the non digit `string`

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/read-file-line-by-line-using-cplusplus and than split the line and check if they contain commands.

Comment: A string or a line of input consists **entirely** of characters. Some of those characters might represent digits. Once you've identified those digit characters, you can convert them to a numeric value.

Answer (score -1):

Specifically it would depend on where the input is coming from, but generally I would approach it with parsing. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// Prototype
void runCommand(std::string action, int amount);
void parseCommand(std::string rawCommand, std::vector<std::string>& command);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> command;       // Vector of strings that will take the command
    std::string stringInput;

    parseCommand(stringInput, command);    // Separate the raw command into different strings (command[0] and command[1])
    runCommand(command[0], stoi(command[1])); // Run the command

    return 0;
}

void runCommand(std::string action, int amount)
{
    if (action == "add")  // If the command is to add, call the add function
    {
        // add(amount);
    }
    else if (action == "cancel")   // If the command is to cancel, call the cancel function
    {
        // cancel(amount);
    }
}

// This function will take the string rawCommand, parse it into different strings,
// and put the parsed string into the vector command. Command is taken by reference
// so it can modify the original vector object.
void parseCommand(std::string rawCommand, std::vector<std::string>& command)
{   
    std::stringstream stringStream;         // Convert the string input to a std::stringstream
    std::string stringTransfer;             // This string will be a part of the command input

    stringStream << rawCommand;            // Converting the stringInput into a stringStream

    // parse the line separated by spaces
    while (std::getline(stringStream, stringTransfer, ' '))
    {
        // put the command in the vector
        command.push_back(stringTransfer);
    }
    // Clear the command to get it ready for the next potentintial command
    command.clear();
}
```

Of course you'll have to declare all the variables. I'm a noob myself so someone else might have a better method.